# Retrieving doubles from string - simple problem

Tags: java, strings, parsing

The problem is not very complicated (I mean it is easy to solve it), but the question is how to make it in the easiest way (Java)

Input String:

```
String inputString = "[value=20][param=304.2][indicator=1500]";
```

Expected output: array of `double`s : [20.0][304.2][1500.0]

Sample solution:

```
String[] chunks = inputString.split("=");
String valueStr = chunks[1].substring(0, chunks[1].indexOf(']'));
String paramStr = chunks[2].substring(0, chunks[2].indexOf(']'));
String indicatorStr = chunks[3].substring(0, chunks[3].indexOf(']'));
// parsing by Double.parseDouble forming an array and returning it as a result.
```

What other (smarter) way would you propose using Java?

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if using regex is overkill, but it does open up for a fairly concise and (in my opinion) readable solution.

```
public class ArgumentParser {
    public static final Pattern KEY_VALUE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\[([a-zA-Z]+)=(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)\\]");

    public Map<String, Double> parse(String str) {
        Map<String, Double> values = new HashMap<>();

        Matcher matcher = KEY_VALUE_PATTERN.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String key = matcher.group(1);
            Double value = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(2));
            values.put(key, value);
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Edit: The question did ask for an array of doubles to be returned, but that should be trivial to obtain once the parsing is done. Alternatively the parse-method could be modified to only extract the values.

Comment: The regular expression should probably allow an optional negative sign.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to allow for this.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the *easiest* code, you might want to consider *correct* and *robust* code.

Assume following input: `[ param=40.2] [foobar =20] junk [=1500]`. Your code will actually parse this, even though that is likely to be wrong. You have to test if the input actually conforms to a certain format. During parsing, you throw away the information from the labels like `param`, and rather rely on the order. If you don't check for validity, and the format changes unexpectedly, you'll have hard to trace bugs.

I would suggest you parse the data into a `Map<String, Double>`. The parsing can easily be done by regexes, e.g. the pattern `\G \s*\[\s* ([^=]+) \s*=\s* ([^\]]*) \s*\]\s*` (spaces are insignificant – use the `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag). This is laxer than your `substr` parsing, but is able to reject malformed input. This also asserts that the matches are adjacent, so no junk will be in between.

Next, you iterate through all matches, updating the `Map` each time. The regex does not attempt to parse valid doubles – I'd let possible `NumberFormatException`s from `Double.parseDouble(...)` bubble up. Likewise, you should complain when the parsed data does not contain `value`, `param` and `indicator` fields. Note that this is a semantic constraint that should be tested *after* the parsing.

I won't show a reimplementation taking these points into consideration because BjoernH's answer already implements the relevant points.